# Activating virtualenv and opening Jupyter notebooks from a single terminal command

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, zsh, zshrc

I'd like to be able to open my projects easily using one command in terminal instead of doing what I normally do. I tried creating a command like this in my .zshrc:

```
my_project() {
    cd my_folder
    source venv/bin/activate
    jupyter notebook
}
```

Normally if I enter these commands one at a time it opens fine. But I'd rather just run my command and it do everything for me and automatically launch the notebook. When I run this however, it just goes into the folder and stops without running the rest of the commands after it. How do I make it run them one after another?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out! You can run commands after one another by using a semicolon (;). For example using the above code:

```
my_project() {
cd my_folder;
source venv/bin/activate;
jupyter notebook;
}
```